# How to make a checkbox for each row that passes the result into another td

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a html table where every row would have a checkbox. By clicking on that checkbox it should take the device name and show the result in 3rd td of the table. But it is updating a single row of the 3rd td:

HTML :

```
<table id="MYtable" class="table table-bordered">
 <thead>
  <tr class="info">
  <th>CheckBox</th>
  <th>device name</th>
  <th> status</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody class="parameter_table">
  <% @my_devices.all.each do |device| %>
  <tr id="tr_rdkb_<%=device.id %>">
  <td >
  <input  type="checkbox" class="checkBox" name="checkBox[]" 
  onchange="clickedBox(this.name)">
  </td>
  <td class="deviceName" id="deviceName" style="word-break:break-all;">
   <%= device.deviceName%> 
   </td>
   <td class="Selected_Device" id="Selected_Device">
   <b  style="float: right; color: orange;">loading..</b>
   </td>
   </tr>
   <% end %>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

Java Script :

```
function webPaDeviceClickedBox(checkBoxName) {
  var values = new Array();
  var selected_device_id;
  var selected_device_name;

  $.each($("input[name='" + checkBoxName + "']:checked").closest("td")
    .next("td"), function () {
      values.push($(this).text().trim())
    });
  document.getElementById("deviceName").value = values.join("\n");
  selected_device_id = '#Selected_Device';
  selected_device_name = values.join("\n");
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "getSelectedDeviceType",
    data: {
      mac: selected_device_name.trim(),
    },
    success: function (result) {
      $('#cover-spin').hide();
      if (result !== "") {
        if (result.includes("On-line")) {
          $(selected_device_id).html("");
          $(selected_device_id).append(result");
          } else if (result.includes("Off-line")) {
          $(selected_device_id).html("");
          $(selected_device_id).append(result");
         }
      } else {
        $(selected_device_id).html("");
        $(selected_device_id).append("Not Selected ");
      }
    }
  });
}
```

On the click on the checkbox I'm getting the device status, but it updates the 1st row of the table. If I click the 3rd checkbox it gets 3rd device status but in table it updates the 1st device status instead.

Comment: You need to give each checkbox a unique ID that you can address it by.

Comment: but the table is dynamic. how can i give unique id to each status cell

Comment: Outside of your loop you initialise a row counter variable to 1 then increment after each row and append to a row id, e.g. tr id="myrow" + rowNo